# Почему не работает position:fixed

Tags: html, css

Почему мой `div` с такими стилями

```html
<div style="position: fixed; top: 30px; 
        right: 30px; z-index: 999999999; height: 100px;
         width: 100px; background: red;"></div>
```

не фиксируется на одном месте, а плавает вместе со страницей?

Comment: не знай, все должно работать, вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/martdn/kwmbxm49/1/)

Comment: что значит _плавает вместе со страницей_?

Comment: По идее он должен висеть на одном месте в позиции top: 30px; right: 30px; когда прокручивается страница. А он вместе со страницей поднимается вверх.

Comment: так он и должен "плавать со страницей", вы с position:absolute не перепутали?)

Comment: добавьте разметку вокруг. а еще лучше приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Да я все позиционирования уже перепробовал. Вот  пример https://uventa.net синий кубик fixed, красный absolute. Оба уезжают вверх. Хотя один из них должен оставаться как кнопка задать вопрос

Comment: Код, необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы, должен быть добавлен в сам вопрос

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed работает относительно вьюпорта. А ещё относительно контекста, который создаётся трансформацией (свойство transform).
На разное поведение в хроме и в файрфоксе можно напороться в бутстраповской карусели, потому что для файрфокса там анимируется свойство left а для webkit - анимируется transform (или -webkit-transform).
http://jsfiddle.net/1dgtdqh9/

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content context">
    <div class="fixed"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {background-color:#eee;}
.wrapper {height: 100px; overflow-y:auto; position: relative; background-color: #fff;}
.content {
  height: 500px; width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;  
 }
 .context {  
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  transform: translate(0,0);
 }
.fixed {position: fixed; width: 50px; height: 50px; right: 2em; top: 1em; background-color:#f00}
```

Извините, кого ввёл в заблуждение ответом:

Это фича хрома и браузеров на его основе. Fixed он должен быть фиксированным по отношению к viewport, смотреть надо спецификацию css. Но Хром стал делать поправку на контекст родительского блока, это когда у родителя есть свойство absolute или relative. Правильное поведение можно посмотреть в Файрфоксе. Лечится это множеством разных способов реализации, я бы например, такую важную штуку как фиксированный элемент выносил поближе к открывающему или закрывающему тегу body.

Comment: согласен, в лисе все работает.

Comment: А пример можно?

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае было css свойство will-change: transform; оно ломало правльную работу fixed, как я понял блок прилипал вместо верха окна браузера к верху родительского блока у которого было прописано данное css свойство

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так, должно работать.

```
position: fixed!important;
```